# Does Polypurpose Panacea allow a 1 hour full rest?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

According to [this](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Rest), a standard daily rest duration should be around 8 hours.

One of the [Polypurpose Panacea](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/polypurpose-panacea) effects says:

> Sleep: You enter a pleasant and restful sleep for at least 1 hour unless wakened. If you would normally begin sleeping at this time, when the panacea ends you continue sleeping normally.

It does not explicitly mention that the sleep could replace a 8 hours (or more) rest, however the definition, especially the use of the term "restful sleep" leave me in doubt.

Assuming a character uses this effect and slept for at least one hour before beeing woken up, could this effect of Polypurpose Panacea replace a 8 hours (or even 24) rest ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 8 hours but it does give you an instant and guaranteed 1 hour rest, reducing Exhaustion to Fatigue in the process which is not to be underestimated. [Nap Stack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/n/nap-stack/) on the other hand does give you a full 8 hours quickly, but it requires at least 2 hours to do that, and gives extra benefits for longer use.

Answer (score 1):

As you noted: It does not explicitly mention that the sleep could replace a 8 hours (or more) rest. So it doesn't. It makes you sleep for one hour, which has the effect of sleeping 1 hour, not 8.

The sleep it provides is restful, so after it you only need 7 hours of sleep to get a full rest.

Useless? For the average adventurer probably, but not for the average townsfolk with insomnia issues.